# How to only field names(not field values) of a particular document using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm a beginner in both MongoDB and node.js. Actually, I'm trying to get the names of a particular document but I wonder how to do that.
Let me elaborate in detail :
if "a" is a collection which contains document named "student" and "student" contains fields like

```
{
    "_id: "student",
    "name": "alex",
    "roll": "3",
    "age":"13"
}
```

then how to get the field names in this `["name","roll","age"]` format
By trying this:

```
db.collection("user").find({ "_id": "student" }).toArray(function(err, result) {
    console.log(result)
})
```

is giving all the fields with their values.

Answer (score 0):

try :

`db.collection("user").find({"_id":"student"}, {name:1}).toArray(function(err, result) {console.log(result)}`

if you want to exclude fields :

`db.collection("user").find({"_id":"student"}, {roll:0, age:0}).toArray(function(err, result) {console.log(result)}`

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
db.collection("user",function(err,user){
   var array = [];
   user.findOne(function(err,doc){
     for (key in doc) array.push(key);
   });
   console.log(array);
});
```